# jQuery Isotope Filtering effect

Tags: jquery, drupal

I embedded the jquery Isotope filtering function in my drupal page as you can see here:

http://sarahraaber.com/artwork_v2

The filter works fine, the only thing I don't get is, why the "filter effect" as you can see here:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html

wont work. I tried the same stuff on a simple html page and anything works fine after 2 minutes work.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved by adding the needed CSS Code -.-

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html